# Where to find Apache Solr port configuration/setting in Apache Solr filesystem or source files or in which xml file can I find it

Tags: solr

In Apache Solr 8.4.1, where could I find the solr port that will listen to Solr REST API request.
Where to find Apache Solr port configuration/setting in Apache Solr filesystem or source files or in which xml file can I find it.

Answer (score 1):

At the root of your Solr installation, you will find a `bin` folder that contains the scripts used to interact with Solr instances (this is what we have [here](https://github.com/apache/solr/tree/main/solr/bin)).

The port Solr binds to and other settings are defined in `solr.in.sh` (or `solr.in.cmd` if you are on a windows machine). As stated in that file :

> Settings here will override settings in existing env vars or in bin/solr.  The default shipped state of this file is completely commented.

By default, you should have this :

```
#SOLR_PORT=8983
```